# In signed apk google plus user verification is failing

Tags: android, google-plus, proguard

Exported apk not allowing G plus authentication. Getting toast message as **An internal error occured** . and it is working fine with the apk of its bin folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error was because of the SHA1 fingerprint.Previously I took my SHA1 key from

**window > preference > android > build**

This SHA1 fingerprint will work only for the apk of bin folder.

I should have take the SHA1 fingerprint getting while exporting or by using the Keytool.